# "accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." with only one thread

Tags: c#

When attempting to do the following:

```
textBoxChat.AppendText("Connected succesfully!" + Environment.NewLine);
```

I get the following error:

```
    An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBoxChat' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Yet I only have one thread.

EDIT:
All code relevant to error:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public string ip, port;
        NetComm.Client client = new NetComm.Client();

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.Connected += new NetComm.Client.ConnectedEventHandler(client_Connected);
        }

        private void client_Connected()
        {
            textBoxChat.AppendText("Connected succesfully!" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
     }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You are calling a method from another thread.  Background worker?  Awaitable method?

Comment: Obviously, `NetComm.Client` is raising the event on another thread. If you didn't write that class, consult the documentation. If you did, show us how the event is raised.

Comment: one way to see that @mikez is correct is to place a breakpoint in your event handler.  When the breakpoint is triggered, select `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Threads`.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, `NetComm.Client.Connected` is being raised from a different thread. To update your UI from a different thread you can call [Control.Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just change your event handler code to something like this:

```
private void client_Connected()
{
    Action updateUi = () => textBoxChat.AppendText("Connected succesfully!" + Environment.NewLine);
    this.Invoke(updateUi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by moving the code to the Form_Load().